# Angular component not visible via selector (sidenav)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm confused. I've this code inside my `app.component.html` file:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

This way my sidenav is not visible but when I put the sidenav directly into the file it's visible and inside the DOM:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav id="mobile-menu-nav" class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true" mode="over" position="end">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I've double checked everything and my `<app-sidenav></app-sidenav>` exists:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSidenav} from '@angular/material';
import {SidenavService} from '../services/sidenav-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.css']
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('sidenav') public sidenav: MatSidenav;

  constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.sidenavService.setSidenav(this.sidenav);
  }
}
```

And also the component is included inside my `app.module.ts`... What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that in `<app-sidenav>` you include `<mat-sidenav>`. Try leaving only the content in the component and return `<mat-sidenav>` tag to the `<mat-sidenav-container>`. Something like this,

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav id="mobile-menu-nav" class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true" mode="over" position="end">
    <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```